# iphone - Hide the annotation view in map view

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

In my view, i've nav bar at the top and remaining view is filled with map view.
My Map view has pins and on click of pin, it will show annotations also.
In the top right nav bar i've a button and on click of it, i want to remove the annotation view that popped up. (what ever annotation view is there, i want to remove from the view).
Can some one tell me how to do it.

The simple task we can do is to send some touch event to the map view which will hide it..... am i right. how to do it?

Comment: I guess you want to hide the `callOutView`, not the annotation itself. Your question should have read, **How to hide the callOutView in map view?**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To hide the callout all you need to do is deselect the selected annotation. You do that by using...

```
- (void)deselectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

For example:

```
[mapView deselectAnnotation:[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

assuming `mapView` is what you named your MKMapView instance.

Comment: I don't want to remove the annotations........ When ever you click on a pin, it will popup annotation view. Click another pin and it will hide previous one and will open another annotation view over clicked pin. Now if you click on some area in the map, it will hide all the annotation view (if any). I want to achieve this functionality on click of a button.

Comment: @Satyam svv: You should rephrase your question to reflect what you actually want to do, instead of down voting this answer.

Comment: OK. As @Simon has explained, it's actually the callout you want to hide. I'll update the answer to show how to hide the callout.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not writing my question properly. This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot. Keep smiling, I increased the voting and also marked the answer as accepted.