# How to remove pin view?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

In my app i have a MapView and one annotation. The first touch on the pin showing it's view, but i can't find the to remove/hide it on another touch.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removes the specified annotation object from the map view.

```
- (void)removeAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
```

Parameters

annotation:
The annotation object to remove. This object must conform to the MKAnnotation protocol.

To remove annotation view only check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896558/iphone-hide-the-annotation-view-in-map-view)

```
[mapView deselectAnnotation:[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to remove MKPinAnnotationView only!